# How do I get Swagger to list my owin api controllers

Tags: rest, swagger, owin

I've installed the Swashbuckle 5.6.0 (currently the latest) in my AspNet 5 WebApi project. I get swagger UI to show up, but none of my api methods gets listed.

I mucked around forever with no success, then made a clean start. From a working API I just installed Swashbuckle and left it at that to make it easier to releate to.

The API is hosted in IIS, not Express. It is tried out though.

How do I debug this? Or even better, can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Code below; empty lines for readability had to be removed to satisfy stackoverflow, sorry!

Startup

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.InboundClaimTypeMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(
            new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Authority = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IdentityServerApplicationUrl"],
                RequiredScopes = new[] {"gallerymanagement"}
            });
        var config = WebApiConfig.Register();
        app.UseWebApi(config);
    }
}
```

WebApiConfig

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static HttpConfiguration Register()
    {
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
           name: "DefaultRouting",
           routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
           defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
       );
        config.EnableCors();
        // clear the supported mediatypes of the xml formatter
        config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Clear();
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(
            new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json-patch+json"));
        var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
        json.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented;
        json.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
        return config;
    }
}
```

EventsController

```
[EnableCors("*", "*", "GET, POST, DELETE")]
public class EventsController : ApiController
{
    [Route("api/Events/{sub}")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetSingleEvent(string sub)
    {
    }

    [Route("api/Events/")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get()
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You miss to init swashbuckle. 
See https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle, you have to add

```
config
.EnableSwagger(c => c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "A title for your API"))
.EnableSwaggerUi();
```

to WebApiConfig.